# grep *gcc* doesn't match anything

Tags: grep

I'm using the following code

```
$ rpm -qa | grep -i gcc
libgcc-4.8.3-7.fc20.i686
gcc-c++-4.8.3-7.fc20.x86_64
gcc-4.8.3-7.fc20.x86_64
libgcc-4.8.3-7.fc20.x86_64

$ rpm -qa | grep -i *gcc*
$
```

I would expect the second way to do the same as the first, but it prints nothing.  Am I using the `grep` command correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `egrep`, or `grep -E` like this:

```
rpm -qa | egrep -i '.*gcc.*'
```

This uses the supplied search string as a regular expression where the period (.) stands for any character and the asterisk (*) stands for one-or-more of those characters.

What I believe you're trying to use with `rpm -qa | grep -i *gcc*` is a feature of most shells called filename globbing.  This technique doesn't work with grep.  It assumes that you want everything with `gcc` in the string, as in your first example, without the need to specify it explicitly.

Edit:
The difference between `*gcc*` and `.*gcc.*` is the first is actually a syntax error with egrep, though it may not tell you.  The asterisk (*) is a modifier that tells the regular expression parser that you're interested in zero-or-more of the previous character.  In the first expression, there is no previous character because the single quote (') doesn't count.

Comment: Just updated my question. Could you also explain the second part. I couldnt put the second part down as a comment because of formatting issues

Comment: I don't think the OP is _trying_ to use filename globbing -- that's the _problem_. The answer is: always quote regular expressions, so the command should have been `grep -i "*gcc*"` -- except that's wrong, too. `grep -i ".*gcc.*"` would be syntactically correct, but it means the same as `grep -i "gcc"`.